# Solution to equation involving polynomial exponent

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

How would I isolate $x$ in the following equation:
$$ax^2+bx+c=x^{ax^2+bx+c},$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$?

I don't think it's possible to isolate $x$ with basic algebraic manipulation as I've tried.

I've transformed the equation into
$$x=e^{\frac{\ln({q})}{q}},$$
where $q=ax^2+bx+c$, but I don't  think this form has any significance (as $q$ is expressed in terms of $x$).

Since the maximum value of the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln({x})}{x}$ occurs at $x=e$, shouldn't this mean that
$$e^{\frac{\ln({e})}{e}}=\sqrt[e]{e} \implies x\le \sqrt[e]{e}?$$

Moreover, is the general form
$$p(x)=x^{p(x)},$$
where $p$ is some polynomial significant in math? If so, to what extent are they solvable?

Any solutions or suggestions towards a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are correct: it is not possible to isolate $x$ with basic algebraic manipulation

Comment: Equations like this often don’t have a good closed form. When they do, they often use the Lambert W function, but I’m not seeing how to use it here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the reference! Would this mean that most solutions to equations like these are approximated numerically? Or are there alternative methods to solving equations in the general form I've edited into the question?

Comment: Yeah, numerical methods are really the best you can do, in general. Luckily, in the real world, these sorts of problems don’t come up very naturally very often.

Comment: I think you can say that any solutions (of $x$) must be in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson. I do not see why. Take $a=b=c=1$ for a solution $x=1.40155$

Comment: Oh yeah I didn’t think of that. Maybe we can get some other bound for $x$ though?

Comment: Perhaps investigating the properties of $\frac{\ln({n})}{n},n\in\mathbb{R}^+$ would give some insight into a potential bound (given that $x=e^{\frac{\ln({q})}{q}}$ is correct)?

Comment: Seems you can have $0,1,2$ or $3$ solutions maximum. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oshkhn2imo At least I didn't manage to get $4$.

Comment: I was mistaken $4$ are possible https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hychdowwiq, so now I'm not even sure about the possible number of solutions... Seems with $a\ll -1$ and $b\gg 1$ some crazy behaviour can be found.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $x\le \sqrt[e]{e}$