# Finding the upper bound of $x$ satisfying $ax^2+bx+c=x^{ax^2+bx+c}$

Tags: solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds

> I want to find the upper bound value of $x$ in
> $$ax^2+bx+c=x^{ax^2+bx+c}, \tag{1}$$
> where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

This is how I've approached the problem:

Let $q=ax^2+bx+c$.
Then, $(1)$ becomes
$$\begin{align} q&=x^q \\ \log_x({q})&=q \\ \frac{\ln({q})}{\ln({x})}&=q \\ \tag{2}x&=e^{\frac{\ln({q})}{q}}.\end{align}$$

Let $f(x)=\frac{\ln({x})}{x}$. The maximum of $f$ would occur at an $x=a$ such that $f'(a)=0$.

We find that
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln({x})}{x^2},$$
and so
$$\frac{1-\ln({x})}{x^2}=0 \implies x=e$$

With reference to $(2)$, the largest value possible for $x$ is thus
$$x=e^{\frac{\ln({e})}{e}}=\sqrt[e]{e}.$$

---

I have a few questions about this:

- Is this correct?
- I am unsure of the validity of $(2)$ and its use since $q$ is expressed in terms of $x$.
- Does the relationship between $q$ and $x$ affect the logic of the argument?
- Furthermore, is my derivation of the maximum of $f$ correct? I made an assumption that the maximum occurs at $x=a$ such that $f'(a)=0$, but can't really back it up.
- Overall, how was the wording of the work? I'm currently at the high school level, so I'm not too familiar with this type of math formatting.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Note: this question is a "byproduct" of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164476/solution-to-equation-involving-polynomial-exponent) one.

Comment: Are you only interested in any upper bound or the supremum? For the sup some work would be needed to show it could be achieved.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh I think this is impossible because you should solve the equation $x = \exp(\frac{\ln q}{q})$ (which can't be solved without numerical methods)

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh To be honest, I have no idea what a supremum is. I should say that I want to find the largest value $x$ can possibly be. Would this be the upper bound?

Comment: The supremum is the least upper bound. For example, $-(1-x)^2$ is always less than $5$. However, a better bound would be to say it is always less than or equal to $0$. We say $0$ is a supremum for $-(1-x)^2$ as it is the tightest bound we can say. All other bounds will be larger than zero.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. It seems the supremum is what I'm looking for, then (as it is the tightest bound)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is mostly correct, and the wording seems fine to me. Another way to start would be,

$$q=x^q\\ q^{1/q}=x\\ x=e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$$

Then, since $e^x>0$ is increasing on the Reals, finding the maxima of $\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$, if they exist, will find at least some of the maxima of $e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$, and using the derivative to do so is the right approach, though it is also necessary to use a second derivative to determine whether a point is a maximum. Specifically, if $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a)<0$, then the point at $x=a$ is a maximum of $f$. In this case, $f''(x)=\frac{2\ln(x)-3}{x^3}$ so $f''(e)=\frac{2\ln(e)-3}{e^3}\approx -0.0498<0$ and thus we can be sure that this is a maximum of $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ and of $e^\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$.

However, these cases do not cover all possible maxima of $e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$. For example, consider $q(x)=x^2+x+10$ for which $e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$ has a global maximum at $x=a=-\frac{1}{2}$, but $q(x)=e$ has no Real solutions, and $e^\frac{\ln(q(a))}{q(a)}\approx 1.263<e^\frac{1}{e}$. This can be explained by taking the derivative of the whole function:
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}=e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln(q)}{q}=e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}\frac{dq}{dx}$$
Here, $e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\ge0$ as $e^x>0$ and so even if $e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}=0$ at an asymptote of $\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$, this point can't be a maximum. Then, $\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}=0$ describes the same maxima that we have found already, and $\frac{dq}{dx}$ is a polynomial for any polynomial $q$, so its zeros could be additional maxima of the function, as with the example $q(x)=x^2+x+10$ where $q'(x)=0$ at $x=a=-\frac{1}{2}$, where the value of the function at the maximum is exactly $e^\frac{\ln(q(a))}{q(a)}=\frac{39}{4}^\frac{4}{39}\approx 1.263<e^\frac{1}{e}$. Using the second derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}\frac{dq}{dx}=e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\left(\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}\frac{dq}{dx}\right)^2+e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}\frac{dq}{dx}\\=e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\left(\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}\frac{dq}{dx}\right)^2+e^\frac{\ln(q)}{q}\left(\frac{2\ln(q)-3}{q^3}\left(\frac{dq}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{1-\ln(q)}{q^2}\frac{d^2q}{dx^2}\right)$$
Which can be evaluated with our example to find $e^\frac{\ln(q''(a))}{q''(a)}\approx -0.034<0$ and thus this point is indeed a maximum. For functions of this form, the most straightforward way to find a global maximum will typically be to compare all local maxima and pick the largest, though I am sure other methods exist for more general cases. This approach can be used for any polynomial $q$, and for a wide variety of other functions as well. Unfortunately, it does not bring us much closer to solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164476/solution-to-equation-involving-polynomial-exponent) linked problem, but it does help us gain a better understanding of functions of the form $e^\frac{\ln(q(x))}{q(x)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Quite frustrated that I hadn't checked if it was a maxima or minima. I do find functions of the form $e^{\ln(q(x)/q(x)}$ to be quite interesting (at least on a graphical level).

Comment: I agree, having studied them for this problem, I find their properties to be intriguing. I may have to look into them more in the future.